# Convert int[] array to ushort[] array

Tags: c#, arrays, int, ushort

I need to convert an `int[]` array to a `ushort[]` array in order to use the method `Array.Copy()` from theses two types of array.

Which method should I use ?

Comment: A loop is an accepted method to iterate over arrays or lists. I doubt there is a pre-made implementation for this, since you will need to deal with values of  `int` that do not fit into a `ushort`. So you need to implement error handling. As long as you have only primitive types, you'll automatically have a copy of the data, so potentially, you don't even need `Array.Copy()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
var arr = Array.ConvertAll(inputs, val => checked((ushort)val));
```

The advantage of `Array.ConvertAll` here is that it right-sizes the target array *from the outset*, so it never allocates multiple arrays, and can be used conveniently.

The `checked` here causes the `int` to `ushort` conversion to throw an exception if an overflow is detected; this is *not* done by default.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to get a ushort array from an int array is:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] intArr = new int[5]{1,2,3,4,5}; // Creates an array of ints 
        ushort[] ushortArr = new ushort[5];   // Creates an array of ushorts

        // Copy the int array to the ushort array
        for(int i=0; i<intArr.Length; i++){
            ushortArr[i] = (ushort)intArr[i];
        }

        // Prints the ushort array
        foreach(ushort u in ushortArr){
            Console.Write(u+", ");
        }
    }
```

The output of this program is:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
```

note: you need to make sure that the length of the ushort array is the same as the length of the int array.

I believe this is a very simple solution.
I hope it helps :)

Comment: If you say `new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};`, the compiler will figure out the length for you, and if you say `new ushort[intArr.Length];`, then it will automatically get the correct length, no matter how you change the content of `intArr`.

Answer (score 1):

There are cleaner alternatives, but assuming you need to do somethng when an int can't be an unsigned short:

```
    public ushort[] ToUnsignedShortArray(int[] intArray)
    {
        if (intArray == null)
        {
            return new ushort[0];
        }

        var shortArray = new ushort[intArray.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < intArray.Length; i++)
        {
            // add your logic for determining what to do if the value can't be an unsigned short
            shortArray[i] = (ushort)intArray[i];
        }

        return shortArray;
    }
```